# Is it possible to bake texture exactly as they appear in 3D view port?

Tags: texture-baking, uv-image-editor

I am new to Blender, and I just figure out a way to let textures display correctly as how I imagine on my model. I add two source texture images directly in the UV editor, and the textured model looks fine in 3D View Port.
[image: This is the screenshot of my work.]

However, when I try to bake my textures, by selecting "Texture" in Bake Mode and clicking "Bake", the textures disappear and turn to white:
[image: This is the screenshot after I attempt to bake texture.]

I don't know which step I did wrong. Is there anyway to bake textures exactly as how they appear in 3D View port? I've been doing research about this online for two full days and I cannot get it to work. The purpose of my model is to be exported as a game asset to Unity. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you! 
(BTW: The original .blend file is included in the comment to this post in case anyone needs to look at it. Thanks.)

Comment: (I include the .blend file in case anyone needs to look at it: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1ebtj35GSpoRDUyMkdNU01ZUEU/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Probably you baked texture over itself (output image for baking was set the same as the one used as the input), although it would become black in that case. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13479/how-to-generate-final-texture-image-for-complete-designed-scene for baking in BI; the way to bake there is to assign image to bake to in the UV editor with all faces selected; to choose image to bake from add it as a material texture.